# Should I always have a session open?

Tags: php, session

Should I constantly have a session open in my web site with user accounts, or only start it when they are logged in?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do/achieve. When it should be started depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days it is very common to start one immediately, especially if you are doing any kind of use-case logging. If you are doing sessions correctly, the cost is incredibly low.

Comment: Yeah, I just keep the session open, before I was getting some nasty loading errors because I may have initialized it somewhere else.  It's just a lot cleaner to keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on you needs.

For example: An online shopping site can track the users who are logged out but still browsing their site. This will allow them to get some browsing pattern and know what the user look at and probably come up with a recommendation.

This is just one scenario.